# Capturing final stopwatch time

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, time, stopwatch

I want to use this stopwatch (or something similar):

http://www.sivamdesign.com/scripts/dwld/stopwtch.txt

but I will need to capture the final time that it is stopped on, and then store it as a variable (so I can later add it into a database). Is it possible to capture the time as a variable?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the script you provided, you can access the final time via

```
document.clock.stwa.value
```

or to get the parts, you can access the vars *sec*, *min* and *hour*.

What are you planning on doing with the final time?

Edit:
Then you can either post the value via AJAX or just throw form tags around the value textbox and add a submit button (or submit the value when user hits "Stop"). To start on page load, add this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  stopwatch('Start');
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, we might need to store the final time in a database for future records. Is there a way I can make the time automatically start when the page is opened too? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, its much better now it starts automatically. I've never used AJAX before so I've got a bit of a problem...is there a way to make it into a PHP variable? All of the other information on the page will be stored with PHP.

Comment: Read up on how to use AJAX, you'll find thousands of tutorials with google. Then it should be pretty straightforward, just send _document.clock.stwa.value_ in the AJAX request and you'll have it on the server as a PHP variable. If you don't want to learn AJAX, the script could be altered to submit the value in a regular form post to the server when the user hits "Stop"..